# htaccess 301 redirection not working

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

In my site I want to redirect with `http://domain_name.com/blog` to `http://domain_name.com/news` and it should be work with the following criteria also

1. `http://domain_name.com/blog/2012/06/06//blog_title` to `http://domain_name.com/news`
2. `http://domain_name.com/blog/blog/?cat=2` to `http://domain_name.com/news`

How would I do this?

Comment: whatever 2012/06/06 come needs to redirect news.
here blog only fixed other that in that url will be dynamic, so whatever comes after blog i need to redirect http://domain_name.com/news

Answer (score 0):

Can't test that, but anyway...

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule /
RewriteRule ^/blog/.*$ /news/ [L,R=301]
```

Comment: i dont want to replace the blog to news, where ever the word blog comes it will redirect to the http://domain_name.com/news 
eg : 
http://domain_name.com/blog/2012/06/06//blog_title to http://domain_name.com/news   

not 

http://domain_name.com/news/2012/06/06//blog_title

Comment: Indeed, that's exactly what it does.